# SQLzoo | JOIN operation

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to solve question 13 of JOIN tutorial in SQLzoo (http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations)

The question ask to list the film title and the leading actor for all of the films 'Julie Andrews' played in.

I've produced the following script, but somewhere is wrong.

```
SELECT title, actor.name FROM
  movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
        JOIN actor ON actor.id=actorid
    WHERE ord=1
    AND title = ALL
      (SELECT title FROM 
         movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
               JOIN actor ON actor.id=actorid
           WHERE actor.name='Julie Andrews')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right script is:

```
SELECT m.title,
       a.name
FROM   movie m
       JOIN casting c
         ON m.id = c.movieid
            AND c.ord = 1
       JOIN actor a
         ON a.id = c.actorid
WHERE  m.id IN (SELECT m1.id
                FROM   movie m1
                       JOIN casting c1
                         ON m1.id = c1.movieid
                       JOIN actor a1
                         ON a1.id = c1.actorid
                WHERE  a1.name = 'Julie Andrews')
```

I've noticed that if I'm using the column m.title as a proxy in the WHERE statement the script takes more time to run and the SQLzoo server stop it. Instead, using the m.id column makes things faster to load. Perhaps is a good practice always prefer to check digits instead of letters when possible.

Another issue on my initial scripts was setting an EQUAL operator instead of IN. The sub-query returns more than 1 row, thus is necessary the use of an IN operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT title, name
  FROM movie, casting, actor
  WHERE movieid=movie.id
    AND actorid=actor.id
    AND ord=1
    AND movieid IN
    (SELECT movieid FROM casting, actor
     WHERE actorid=actor.id
     AND name='Julie Andrews')
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Solution:

```
select movie.title, actor.name FROM movie
JOIN casting
ON casting.movieid = movie.id
JOIN actor
ON actor.id = casting.actorid
where ord = 1 and 
movieid in (select movieid from casting join actor on id = actorid where name = 'Julie Andrews' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way to you get it.

```
SELECT m.title, a.name FROM
  movie m JOIN casting c ON c.id = m.movieid
        JOIN actor a ON a.id=m.actorid
    WHERE m.ord=1
    AND m.title = ALL
      (SELECT m1.title FROM 
         movie m1 JOIN casting c1 ON c1.id=m1.movieid
               JOIN actor a1 ON a1.id=m1.actorid
           WHERE a1.name='Julie Andrews');
```

If you have to display your tables with column names then i will be modify this query

Answer (score 0):

```
select title, name from movie
join casting on (casting.movieid =movie.id)
join actor on (actor.id = casting.actorid)

where ord =1
and movieid in (select movie.id from movie
join casting on (casting.movieid =movie.id)
join actor on (actor.id = casting.actorid)

where name = 'Julie Andrews')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title,name
FROM movie
    JOIN casting ON (movieid=movie.id AND ord=1)
    JOIN actor   ON (actor.id=actorid)
WHERE movieid IN (SELECT movieid
                  FROM movie
                       JOIN casting ON (movieid=movie.id)
                       JOIN actor   ON (actor.id=actorid)
                  WHERE actor.name='Julie Andrews')
```

Starting from subquery: Select all the 'movieid' of movies with 'Julie Andrews' in them and use it as a filter in WHERE

Now join all the 3 tables with a specific condition that you only select the 'actorid' with 'ord'=1  ('ord'=1 means that the actors name is on top of order of actors). This will only select the rows/records containing the actor ids of lead actors. In the end just retrieve these leading actors name from 'actor' table.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT title,name FROM
casting join movie on movie.id=movieid and ord=1
        join actor on actor.id=actorid
WHERE  movie.id in (
SELECT movie.id FROM 
movie join casting on movie.id=movieid
      join actor on actor.id=actorid
                  WHERE name='Julie Andrews' )
```